# Question is available, but the answer and its comments are not visible

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments, deleted-answers

Yesterday I asked a question and someone had replied as comments. More than 10 or 11 comments are shared with me and the one who helped me to solve my question. But today I am not able to view the comments. It seems the one who replied disappeared.

Comment: here is the link of question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332073/get-the-values-at-the-time-of-selecting-in-listview-in-button-rather-than-click

Comment: And this is the [deleted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af64l.png). _“Ehm... How you explained your achieve cause confusion. Explain better”_ isn’t an answer. The post author — or even you — is free to edit this and write a proper answer, based on the comments, if they indeed answered your question. Your clarifications, in turn, should be edited into the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question has an 'answer' but it has been deleted. Why? Because it's not really an answer to your question. It's a (poor) comment at best. That's why it was removed, and the comment chain is 'collateral damage'.

[Here is a screenshot of the page, including the deleted answer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm2D9.jpg) The links point to the following questions:

- [Android - Keep ListView's item highlighted once one has been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281000/android-keep-listviews-item-highlighted-once-one-has-been-clicked)
- [Start activity without showing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571887/start-activity-without-showing-it)